# Why can't I concatenate variables to the end of my SQL query?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, concatenation

I am trying to use parameters in my API calls to add a row with the given values to a table in an SQLite database. It works when I'm just concatenating a variable to the end of the query, but not when I'm concatenating multiple variables and some extra SQL queries (such as converting variables to a certain data type.

I noticed that the SQL queries are color-coded in a specific way, but the concatenated parts are colored like regular Strings. Here is the code:

```
let id = req.query.id;
        let filename = req.query.filename;
        let is_folder = req.query.is_folder;
        let parent = req.query.parent;
        let guid = req.query.guid;
        let size = req.query.size;
        await initDatabasePromise;
        const result = await database.all(`INSERT INTO content VALUES (` + id + `, CONVERT(varchar(512), ` + filename + `), ` + is_folder
            + `, ` + parent + `, CONVERT(varchar(64), ` + guid  + `), ` + size  + `, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`);
        res.json(result);
```

And here is an image that shows the color coding, in case I am misinterpreting it:

Here is a portion of my code, which shows the color coded parts

[image: Here is a portion of my code, which shows the color coded parts]

And this is the error that I get:

```
[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: undefined] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ")": syntax error] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
```

And here is the query string saved as a variable and printed out. I have no idea why it printed two of them, or why everything turned to undefined in the first one:

```
INSERT INTO content VALUES (undefined, CONVERT(varchar(512), undefined), undefined, undefined, CONVERT(varchar(64), undefined), undefined, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

INSERT INTO content VALUES (3, CONVERT(varchar(512), Untitled), true, 1, CONVERT(varchar(64), 012345), 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I'm new to this, so I might be doing something completely wrong. Maybe I am converting data types incorrectly? Maybe the rest of the SQL query is being interpreted as one giant String? Does anyone have any tips that might help me out?

Comment: Learn to use parameters so you don't have problems caused by munging SQL query strings.

Comment: And post code as code, not as an image.

Comment: Can you please create a query variable and store the query string in it before execution and also print the query string and share the string to look at.

Comment: @TheifMaster I was trying to show the color-coded parts, which unfortunately cannot be done directly in StackOverflow. But I will edit the question to also include the code.

Comment: @NayanLathiya I edited my post to include the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [node-sqlite3 documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) on how to use parameters in your queries. You definitely do **not** want to take raw values from the query string and concatenate them directly into your SQL queries as it leaves your application vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Your query should instead look something like this:

```
const result = await database.all(
    `INSERT INTO content VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, 
    [req.query.id, req.query.filename, req.query.is_folder, req.query.parent, req.query.guid, req.query.size],
);
```

You could also used named parameters:

```
const result = await database.all(
    `INSERT INTO content VALUES ($id, $filename, $is_folder, $parent, $guid, $size, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, {
    $id: req.query.id,
    $filename: req.query.filename,
    $is_folder: req.query.is_folder,
    $parent: req.query.parent,
    $guid: req.query.guid,
    $size: req.query.size,
});
```

Even then I probably would not pass query string parameters directly into your query unless you specifically know they are going to be values you can trust...you probably need to 'sanitize' the types/values as well; for instance

- `is_folder` is something you would want to convert to an integer or boolean true/false value
- `id`, `parent`, and `size` are likely things you would want to convert to integers
- `filename` is something where you might want to strip off slashes/folders and keep just the filename

There are other things to consider as well from a database perspective:

- `id` itself might be something you want to auto-increment so it does not have to be manually specified at all
- Your timestamp columns could be defaulted in the database so you do not have to specify them on your INSERT queries.

You also might want to be more explicit with your `INSERT` statement, so rather than just the values you are specifying, specify the column as well.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO content (id, filename, is_folder, parent, guid, size, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```